# Django REST Framework: Can you mix API views with template views?

Tags: reactjs, django, api, templates, django-rest-framework

I am developing a web application using Django and React, and using Django REST Framework to have them talk to each other.

I am trying to create a Django view that could handle both AJAX requests from React code **AND** render Django HTML templates. To accomplish this, I am using the `TemplateHTMLRenderer` class from Django REST Framework that I found [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/#rendering-html). However, when I try to `fetch()` data from that view from React I do not receive any valid response.

Here is my view:

```
# URL: "/"
class IndexView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = "dictionary/index.html"

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        definitions = Definition.objects.all()
        return Response({"definitions": definitions})
```

And here is how I am trying to `fetch()` datafrom React:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data  => {
        this.setState({
            definitions: data
        });
    },
    error => {
        this.setState({
            alert('ERROR')
        });
    })
}
```

This code ends up displaying the alert "ERROR".

Apparently, my view is not returning a valid JSON object. How can I change it to provide both rendering and API functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to add `JSONRenderer` to `renderer_classes` and add `application/json` to the HTTP Accept header. Here is some [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/content-negotiation/).